# How can I make this greasekit script open in a new window?

Tags: javascript

This is a special GreaseKit script that is successfully changes some URLs on a page. It is super and I love the person here who wrote it. **but I want to tweak it, so that the link, when clicked, opens in a new window**

```
// the new base url
var base = ' https://www.example.co.uk/wine/order?ie=UTF8&asin=';
// all the links with className 'PrmryBtnMed'
var links  = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0;i < links.length;i++){
// check each link for the 'asin' value
var result = /asin=([\d\w]+)/.exec(links[i].getAttribute('href'));
if(result){
    // make a new url using the 'base' and the 'asin' value
    links[i].setAttribute('href', base+result[1]);
}
}
```

## My guess on how to solve this:

Could someone please tell me how to achieve this? My guess would be to add `link.target="_blank"` somewhere, but I'm not sure exactly where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be correct. Just set that where the other attribute is being set:

```
if(result){
    // make a new url using the 'base' and the 'asin' value
    links[i].setAttribute('href', base+result[1]);
    links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank'); // open in a new window
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside this:

```
if(result){
    // make a new url using the 'base' and the 'asin' value
    links[i].setAttribute('href', base+result[1]);
}
```

Simply add another attribute:

```
links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
```